# Spring: Must Service or Controller or Repository have an interface

Tags: spring

Why must Service, Controller or Repository have an Interface since only 1 class implements them?

2ndly

Why is spring naming convention.

Interface : ABCService
Concrete Class: ABCServiceImpl
..

Should it be more user friendly using the following naming converstion (eclipse ctr-shift-r)

Interface : IABCServices
Concrete Class: ABCService

Answer (score 2):

1) Be default things like `@Transactional` are implemented using [JDK Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).  In order for Spring to create a JDK Proxy at runtime there has to be an interface to implement.  You can't proxy a class.  If you switch to using [CGLib proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch08s05.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types), then the interfaces are not necessary.

2) That is just convention, who but the person who first started doing it can really tell us why? :)  The `IABCServices` naming is primarily used in Microsoft platforms.  Why do we camel case properties and capitalize classes.

One can make a philosophical argument that if the interface is the true definition of the thing, then it should have a 'clean' name.  Why does the 'root definition' of the item have markup on it?  The platform specific/implementation specific items should be the ones with their names marked up.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your first question, these three component types do not necessarily need to implement an interface.  In spring webmvc, it's common to have Controllers that don't implement any interfaces.  If you do use an interface and have one or more concrete classes implement them, then you can wire your application components together by configuration (called dependency injection).  This is useful when you want to use one type of impl for one purpose (say, your production web app), but you want to use a different type of impl for another purpose (for example, using a mock for testing).