# Why declare always Interfaces for DAO

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Why we have always to declare first a `interface` to implement our DAO classes like this

Interface  :

```
public interface IRegion<T extends Serializable> {

    List<T> findAll();

}
```

DAO Class :

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class RegionDAO  implements IRegion < Region > {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Region> findAll() {

        return  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Region").list();
    }

}
```

Controller :

```
@Controller
public class welcome {

    @Autowired
    private IRegion<Region> regionI;
        ....

}
```

But it works also when I keep just my DAO class and I remove the interface

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RegionDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public List<Region> findAll() {

        return  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Region").list();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class welcome {

@Autowired
private RegionDAO regionDAO;
        ....

}
```

So why we have to add interfaces ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring: Must Service or Controller or Repository have an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148345/spring-must-service-or-controller-or-repository-have-an-interface)

Comment: You don't have to. It's a recommendation.

Comment: So there is no drawbacks in performance or something else ?

Comment: what about this `@Transactional` in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19148389/3756879