# component-scan issue @Transactional doesn't work with @Controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I think `@Transactional` doesn't work with other annotations such `@Controller` or I have a problem and confusion with `component-scan` because i get this error :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

Here's my configuration files :

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Hibernate.xml

```
   <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      ....
   </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
      ...
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      ...
   </bean>

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My test Controller

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value="/") 
    public String test() {
        ...
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Region.class,1);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>hibernate.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Show the stack trace. I suspect it's getting thrown from the view, not the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You transactional configuration applies to your root context which also component scans your `controller` package.

Basically you end up with

- Root Context: `@Controller` beans with transactional behavior
- Servlet Context: `@Controller` beans without transactonal behavior

You have duplicate beans. However, the `DispatcherServlet` constructs its MVC stack from the `@Controller` beans in the **Servlet Context** and those are not advised by the transaction interceptor.

You could move your transactional **configuration** to your servlet context or you could move the transactional **behavior** to `@Service` beans declared in the Root Context.

Related:

- [Method not being intercepted by transaction advisor even though "adding transactional method" seen in logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367503/method-not-being-intercepted-by-transaction-advisor-even-though-adding-transact/24389655#24389655)

Comment: It might be worth having a canonical beans-in-different-contexts Spring Q&A.

Comment: @chrylis I agree with you. The `Application context vs servlet context` questions linked in the linked q/a might be good starting point. You did that other good question/answer on `null` `@Autowired`, you might as well do this one.

Comment: I certainly don't understand it as well (part of why I like Spring Boot so much), but I can make an attempt if you're not up for it.

Comment: @chrylis If you make it a community post, I'll consider adding to it. I'm extremely vege right now :|

Comment: **1-** i move my **transactional** configuration to my servlet context and it works thanks a lot man.   **2-** but i didn't understand the second option can you explain it more because i don't have `@Service` beans **3-** How can i see the beans generated by spring ? **4-** How can i avoid having duplicate beans ? i'm afraid it causes me performances issue. if you can edit the answer it will be very good :)

Comment: @user3756879 **2-** Controllers are meant to set up and delegate to the model. You shouldn't do any business logic there. So I was recommending refactoring the code you want to be transactional and move it to `@Service` beans which you can declare in the root context. **3-** You can turn your logs on to TRACE-DEBUG level. What you have to understand how `ApplicationContext`(s) is(are) loaded in a Spring MVC web-app. If you check the linked question, you'll find more in depth discussion. **4-** Yes, you don't want duplicate beans. You have to be careful how you declare them. See the link.

Comment: **(2) -** why ? i feel comfortable with treating business at controller level and I call dao layer simpily, because if i want just load a entity why i have to create a new service layer for it ? **(3) -** I'm new at logging so i create a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478592)

Comment: @user3756879 **2** Separation of concerns. If your logic grows, you don't want to have it in the Controllers. It's up to you, just a suggestion.

Comment: yes maybe because my logics is not big for now but i don't want declare a lot of interfaces i'm little confused about this here's a question i'v create yesterday i need your point if it's possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470573